# Toolbar not visible

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone tell me why, in the storyboard here below, when I arrive from the first tab the toolbar is visible, but when I arrive from the second tab is not visible anymore. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first tab has a navigation controller as the root controller - the second does not.

You can select `SearchVC` in your storyboard and then use the **Editor** - **Embed In** - **Navigation Controller** menu option to add a navigation controller. That might not be how you want your UI. But that would achieve what you want visually ...

**Update:**
Based on discussions with the OP, the issue was that `SearchVC` was adding `EditorVC` as a child view controller and then `EditorVC` in turn would add `ReadVC` to the navigation stack.

`EditorVC`, as it appears above, is embedded within a `UINavigationController`. I suggested that OP remove that `UINavigationController` instance and then push `EditorVC` on to `SearchVC`'s navigation controller and then later when `ReadVC` is displayed from `EditorVC`, again push `ReadVC` on to the existing navigation controller. I believe this should resolve the issues that OP was seeing.

Comment: You can select `SearchVC` in your storyboard and then use the Editor - Embed In - Navigation Controller menu option to add a navigation controller. That might not be how you want your UI. But that would achieve what you want visually ...

Comment: I found another solution, instead of using the segue I was using didSelectItemAt indexPath and then programmatically instantiating let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: readVC). But it works with a modal transition and I want a push transition like the first one.

Comment: With just the storyboard to go on, and without your code, I can't really tell you what works and what does not :) If you want to post the project, I can take a look and tell you what might work.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid that I'd have to see the working project to figure out what is going on since there could be a number of issues. It's hard to tell from an image since I can't see properties for each view controller or how the segues are connected or how things work in code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138779/discussion-between-giovanni-and-fahim).

Comment: Fahim, yours is the right answer! Just need to add a Navigation controller at the beginning of the SearchVC and then push all the subsequent view controllers.

Comment: Happy to hear you got it working, Giovanni :) Good luck with the project and if you need any help, just ping me.